# UMDH & perfmon private bytes

Tags: windows, memory-leaks, perfmon, umdh

I'm trying to use UMDH to find where huge chunks of memory are being allocated but the results I'm getting seem completely absurd.

I start the program, wait for it to reach an equilibrium, and then grab a snapshot with umdh.  Then I perform the activity that causes it to suck up memory, wait for it to reach equilibrium again, and grab another snapshot.  Then I run a diff:

```
umdh -d -v 1.txt 2.txt > diff.txt
```

I'm witnessing 500M of additional private bytes in perfmon (other memory counters also grow accordingly).  UMDH diff shows a "decrease of..." some huge number.  Say what???  Can anyone explain why that might be the case?

Then I commented out all activity in the function that was reported in the largest growth stack.  I performed the above repro again, watched the same 500M growth pattern, but UMDH is reporting a small *increase* in memory use!!! Very small being the operative word there.

The first part really blows my mind.  What would cause UMDH to show a decrease in heap use but perfmon show a rather large increase in allocated memory use by the same process??

I considered thread stacks, but the thread stack count actually goes down.  What else might go into "private bytes"?

Answer (score 0):

Put debug info file, i.e. pdb, into the same path of exe. The following commands worked, replace PID with actual process ID you want to dump:

```
umdh -p:PID -f:memlog1.txt

umdh -p:PID -f:memlog2.txt

umdh memlog1.txt memlog2.txt > result.txt
```

If you see the following warning:

```
Warning:
Warning: UMDH didn't find any allocations that have stacks collected.
Warning: Use gflags to enable allocation stack collection.
Warning: Restart the application for the setting to be in effect.
```

run:

```
gflags -i "full\path\of\exe" +ust
```

and restart the exe before running umdh again.